# Ethernet differential signals

Tags: voltage, ethernet, differential, high-speed, phy

I've 2 questions on Ethernet design:

Suppose I am using a current mode Ethernet PHY which requires termination resistor of 49.9 ohms to VDD on the Ethernet differential lines.

Can I increase the resistor value to 75ohms? Is it OK? Can someone tell me what impact it would have?

Question 2:

Can I place any sort of IC (assume a MUX (specific to an application)) between the magnetics and the RJ-45 connector for 100Mbps ethernet? Will it work or is there something I should take care?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting something between the magnetics and the RJ45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably not. The result is less terminated, of course, giving more crosstalk between symbols.  It's only 25% more, while the signal levels are +/-50% so to speak, so it should still work say with a short patch cable -- but you might not notice what distance it fails at, or under which data patterns.  (If you absolutely must use 75R's, use series-parallel combinations to make 50R proper.)
2. Yes, but NOT AT THE MEDIA SIDE.  You can use one transformer set per connector, and switch the PHY side.  This requires a mux with extra voltage range (with push-pull or current-mode drive, the undriven side swings up to about 2*VDD by transformer action!), so probably needs an auxiliary supply.  Switches are available in such ratings, with low insertion loss and high bandwidth; though they're easier available / better performing at 3.3V (maybe consider a differential / full-bridge / gigabit-style PHY instead??).

You probably still need/want ESD protection for such a switch.  I think they're available with that integrated too, actually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me what do you mean by, "NOT AT THE MEDIA SIDE" ?

Comment: @Newbie Media -- cable, connector. The isolated side is exposed to high voltages from external sources like ESD. Semiconductors cannot connect to this, not for signal purposes anyway. The transformer isolates this dangerous environment from the PHY.

Comment: So, I've to place the MUX between the PHY IC and the magnetics? We cannot place the MUX IC between the discrete magnetics and the RJ-45 connector?

Comment: @Newbie Correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Ohm's law says same current through different resistance causes a proportionally different signal voltage.
2. Yes. Chips intended for muxing Ethernet do exist.

Comment: So, we can place MUX between the Ethernet magnetics & ethernet connector? - This is the MUX partnumber - TMUXHS4212 ? Can we place this MUX between magnetics & connector?

Comment: You need to look at data sheets and application notes where the mux should be connected.

Comment: Ok, but in general, its possible?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?